# Learn Python The Hard Way - Exercise 13 Study Drills

Tags: python, terminal, argv, raw-input

In Learn Python The Hard Way (Exercise 13) the 3rd Study Drill says to "Combine raw_input with argv to make a script that gets more input from a user."

I wrote this script below, intending to have the terminal prompt the user for answers to three questions, then it would print back phrases with those answers integrated into them. However, I get an error about not having enough values to unpack when I try to run it with the following command:

```
python ex13.py
```

I understand that I need more variables to unpack in order for the script to work, so when I type this then the script works but never outputs the variables "first", "second" or "third" (which I don't want it to anyway):

```
python ex13.py first second third
```

I know how to write a script without importing argument variables, but how else can I interpret the study drill? I know I am not understanding the prompt of the study drill correctly but I'm not sure how to write the script differently or even if I am going in the right direction.

Can anyone offer some tips or advice? You don't have to give me the answer outright (I like figuring things out) but I am at a loss for the moment.

MY SCRIPT:

```
from sys import argv

script, color, number, shape = argv

color = raw_input("What is your favorite color? ")
number = raw_input("What is your favorite number? ")
shape = raw_input("What is your favorite shape? ")

print """
This program is called %r and it will determine your
favorite color, number and shape.
""" % script

print "Based on your answers, your favorite color is:", color
print "Your favorite number is:", number
print "And your favorite shape is a:", shape
```

Comment: I figured out how to make the script work by removing ", color, number, shape" befor eth "=". But I'm still getting brackets around my script name now:

$ python ex13.py

What is your favorite color? purple
What is your favorite number? 17
What is your favorite shape? triangle

This program is called ['ex13.py'] and it will determine your
favorite color, number and shape.

Based on your answers, your favorite color is: purple
Your favorite number is: 17
And your favorite shape is a: triangle

$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want your code to do? If you want to have

```
    $ python ex13.py
    $ What is your favorite color? <yourColor>
       ..........
    $ Your favorite color is <yourColor>
```

Then you need to get rid of the part where you set all those values from argv. argv is a list of the arguments passed to python when you invoke it in the command line. The fix you have in your comments sets script = ['ex13.py'] instead of 'ex13.py' for precisely this reason, you're setting script to be a list as opposed to a string.

If you want your code to run so that you pass the script arguments when you run it, you could get rid of your sections calling for raw_input (or you could leave them in, but that would overwrite their values from what you passed in the command line) Try running the code you've posted with

```
    $ python ex13.py <yourColor> <yourNumber> <yourShape>
```

It should work much more closely to what you want.

Comment: Thank you Galen. I think I was trying to do one thing but my problem was that I was doing it two different ways. Either piece of code (upper or lower) was written to do the same thing and I had to remove one or the other to get it to work. I was just looking for a way to write a simple program using both raw_input and argv. I still don't really know what I'm doing so I was just playing around with the study drills hoping to find some direction.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already solved one problem by removing the variables before the `=`, now the only problem is you are getting square brackets around ex13.py.

You see you have to add another variable after script before `=` that is without `input()` and the problem is solved.